# Can Pycharm run jupyter notebook as Vscode do?

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter

Vscode can directly run jupyter notebook by interpreter. But pycharm needs to run files with jupyter server open in local.
[run files in Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAd9U.png)
[run files in Vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWjJK.png)

I prefer using pycharm, but it's really slow, how can i do to make it faster to run the files